# auth log file shows wrong time?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, time

I was looking at the auth log of my server, and I was surprised to see that the times are offset.

```
root@server:/home/admin# date
Tue Jan 12 09:51:36 CET 2016
root@server:/home/admin# tail /var/log/auth.log 
Jan 12 03:10:05 server sshd[18973]: Connection closed by 222.189.40.171 [preauth]
Jan 12 03:25:43 server sshd[18983]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for 210.subnet222-124-218.static.astinet.telkom.net.id [222.124.218.210] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Jan 12 03:25:43 server sshd[18983]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=222.124.218.210  user=root
Jan 12 03:25:45 server sshd[18983]: Failed password for root from 222.124.218.210 port 34563 ssh2
Jan 12 03:25:45 server sshd[18983]: Connection closed by 222.124.218.210 [preauth]
Jan 12 03:41:45 server sshd[18991]: Accepted publickey for admin from 217.111.52.130 port 35090 ssh2: RSA 0b:7a:fa:16:89:a2:ad:9c:06:7f:d1:c8:91:de:23:ae
Jan 12 03:41:45 server sshd[18991]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user admin by (uid=0)
Jan 12 03:42:38 server su[19013]: Successful su for root by admin
Jan 12 03:42:38 server su[19013]: + /dev/pts/0 admin:root
Jan 12 03:42:38 server
```

This the time zone the server has configured:

```
cat /etc/timezone 
Europe/Berlin
```

Maybe it is helpful to know that the server is a VZ guest.

Here is what the commands show in a row:

```
$ su -c "date && tail -n 5 /var/log/auth.log"
Password: 
Tue Jan 12 10:33:24 CET 2016
Jan 12 03:41:45 server sshd[18991]: Accepted publickey for admin from 217.111.52.130 port 35090 ssh2: RSA 0b:7a:fa:16:89:a2:ad:9c:06:7f:d1:c8:91:de:23:ae
Jan 12 03:41:45 server sshd[18991]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user admin by (uid=0)
Jan 12 03:42:38 server su[19013]: Successful su for root by admin
Jan 12 03:42:38 server su[19013]: + /dev/pts/0 admin:root
Jan 12 03:42:38 server su[19013]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by admin(uid=1000)
```

Comment: At the moment, all we can see is a current date, plus some earlier syslogs.  If you'd like us to examine an offset, we need to see the same event in both frames.  Try `sudo date`, or failing that `/bin/su -c date`, *then* the last few lines from `auth.log`.

Comment: @MadHatter, that is exactly the problem the logs are not earlier... the date written there is wrong

Comment: I understand what you're telling us, but I want you to **show** us.  **Edit**: OK, you have, thanks.  I notice that, although you've generated a loggable event, no new line has appeared in your logs (compared with the chunk above).  Is it possible that syslog has stopped logging?  Have you tried restarting it?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a known issue.

I fixed this by restarting rsyslog.

Comment: Normal best practice would be to confirm in comments that the person who'd been helping you had led you to the answer, and inviting *them* to write it up.  But I'm glad you got on top of what was happening!

Comment: restart syslog doesn't work for me, i use inetutils-syslogd.